# Pricing for AWS AppSync GraphQL Subscriptions (Real-Time Updates): Per device or per subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, price

Based on aws appsync pricing https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/pricing/ we're charged 8 cents per million minutes of connection to AppSync.

If we open multiple subscriptions on a single device, does each subscription contribute to the "connected minutes" count, or do they all get lumped together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of subscriptions from same device does not affect the pricing because all real-time updates are pushed via same WebSocket connection.

You are paying for connection minutes + each real-time update + each mutation that triggers them.